# What is fast getting data from redis using key or getting data from oracle single table using primary key

Tags: oracle, caching, web-applications, redis

I want a caching mechanism.. Redis is available, should I use redis, or there is also a oracle table being used as cache.

what is fast: getting data from redis or getting data from oracle using primary key.

Are there any performance statitics for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has block level data caching built in.  You can also use data set "result caching" in Oracle as well.  I would try the Oracle lookup via primary key first, then if your performance requirements are not being met, check the SQL for tuning opportunities (including SGA/PGA memory evaluation, indexes, result caching, ...).